# Open interval equal the union of some closed intervals

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to prove the following $(a, b) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]$ and this is what I have done so far

Since $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, [a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]\subset (a, b)$ then, $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac{1}{n}, b-\frac{1}{n}]\subset (a, b)$

Now to prove the reverse inclusion, let some $x\in (a, b)$ then, $\exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a+\frac{1}{n_{0}}\leq x\leq b-\frac{1}{n_{0}}$

I'm not quite sure if this proof is correct. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Except for  a typo what you have done is fine.